# Like Button counts the likes of a PDF but does not actually post the activity?

Tags: facebook-like, social-networking

I have implemented a Like Button on a page, attempting to allow users to "Recommend" a PDF.  The button appears on the page and seems to function correctly.  Clicking the button opens the comment box; and a user can enter a comment.  However no activity is actually posted on the test user's page.  The counter even increments correctly and the "recommend" action is disabled after the test user has clicked it.  This status is remembered on reload, and the counter is never reset.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="www.bgsd.com/hockey/stats/2012/
East_Side_Hockey_Fall2012.pdf" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" 
data-width="70" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div>
```

Can this button not be applied to this type of resource (PDF)?

Answer (score 0):

Well the PDF can't possible have the meta tags used by Facebook to display a story about that URL - when you put the URL into [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) you'll see.
You probably should/could have pointed the Like plugin at a URL which has a download link (or redirect) to the PDF, not to the PDF URL itself

Comment: Thank you, I suspected this was the case but was intrigued by the button's ability to count likes that never actually posted anywhere.  But it makes sense. We'll have to create download pages like you suggested.

Comment: Provided you serve the meta tags to the requests from Facebook's crawlers, you could redirect other users directly to the PDF, which may be an option for you?